# sinon.useFakeTimers Doesn't Fire Timeout

Tags: javascript, casperjs, sinon

I'm trying to test my timeout functionality using Sinon and CasperJS. This page is showing on a digital sign, so it's not your typical web page - it has a very long lifetime, hence the high timeout value.

Here's the relevant code that I'm trying to test:

```
RiseVision.Image = (function () {
  // Private
  function startTimer() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var img = document.getElementById("image");
      img.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/images/logo-small.png?" + new Date().getTime() + ")";
    }, 900000);
  }

  // Public
  function ready() {
    ...
  }

  return {
    "ready": ready
  };
})();
```

I'm using CasperJS for my tests like so:

```
var e2ePort = system.env.E2E_PORT || 8099;
var url = "http://localhost:"+e2ePort+"/src/widget-e2e.html";
var clock;

casper.test.begin("Image Widget - e2e Testing", {
  test: function(test) {
    casper.start();

    casper.thenOpen(url, function () {
      test.assertTitle("Image Widget", "Test page has loaded");
    });

    casper.then(function () {
      casper.waitFor(function waitForUI() {
        return this.evaluate(function loadImage() {
          // Wait for the background image to be set.
          return document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("style") !== "";
        });
      },
      function then() {
        // Do some assertions here.

        casper.waitFor(function waitForTimer() {
          return this.evaluate(function expireTimer() {
            clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
            clock.tick(900000);

            return document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("style") !==
          "background-image: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/images/logo-small.png);";
          });
        },
        function then() {
          // More assertions here.
        });
      });
    });

    casper.run(function runTest() {
      test.done();
    });
  }
});
```

I know this function is executing because I can successfully log messages from inside of it, but it's just not firing my timer. And it doesn't seem to make any difference if I make the `startTimer` function public.

Any ideas?

Thx.

EDITED - Updated to include more code.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question to include more clarifying code. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean to use a single clock instance and not create one every 50 ms (that's what `waitFor` does).

```
casper.evaluate(function() {
    window._fakeClock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

casper.waitFor(function waitForTimer() {
  return this.evaluate(function expireTimer() {
    window._fakeClock.tick(900001);

    return document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("style") !==
  "background-image: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/images/logo-small.png);";
  });
},
function then() {
  this.evaluate(function() {
      window._fakeClock.restore();
  });

  // More assertions here.
});
```

Comment: A little late. That's more or less a shot in the dark.

Comment: Good point re: creating multiple timers. Fixed that up but it's still not working. I've actually had to skip this test altogether because I just can't get it to work.